# can't access file

Tags: python

I have a problem that I can't access a file with python even though the file is there and I can access it manually.
The following code is the problem:

```
f = '~/backup/backup_20121216.log'
text = open(f, "rb").read()
print text
```

Someone can point me into the right direction?

Comment: What if you expand the `~`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
import os

path = '~/backup/backup_20121216.log'
path = os.path.expanduser(path)
with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
    text = fp.read()
print text
```

Comment: Note: Binary mode may not be appropriate for reading a text file.